# abcpdf7 generated pdf looks bad on mobile - wet paint effect

Tags: .net, pdf, sharepoint-2007, pdf-generation, abcpdf

I'm using abcpdf7 together with my .NET application. I use it to automaticly generate PDFs from prepared HTML code. PDFs look great on pc pdf viewers, but they look really bad, when previewing on mobile phones, e.g. on Android or iOS.
The problem is with fonts, as they often look like a wet paint. Just take a look into the attachement:

[image]
[Numbers generated by abcpdf7 viewed on Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHBhb.jpg)

What can be wrong? Have you ever faced such problem? Do you know a solution?

I have put the original PDF file under this link: http://www.sendspace.com/file/3470uu

Comment: Weird.  Is that a photograph or a screenshot?

Comment: Tomasz - I've added the linked image into the body of your question, to make it clearer. Also, SO prefers that we don't use signatures or tag lines, so I've deleted yours: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Comment: Please also supply the PDF in question.

Comment: I have uploaded it and it is available under the link: http://www.sendspace.com/file/3470uu

Comment: Wow. On my Android the numbers look broken, too, when viewed in Adobe Reader, but they look ok in Polaris Office. In Adobe Reader, BTW, not only the numbers look odd, also some letters rendered with the same font, PIFranklinGothic-BookCond, but none rendered with other fonts. My first guess would be that there is something special with that font that mobile Adobe Reader cannot handle, either the font is broken or the font handling in mobile Adobe Reader is incomplete.

Comment: For test purposes I extracted the font from your file and created a new PDF using that font with iText... and the resulting file also showed such artifacts (actually even worse ones) in Adobe Reader for Android but not on the PC. Additionally it became obvious that the artifacts only appeared after zooming in, without zooming everything is just fine. Unfortunately I don't have an original version of that font. Have you observed that problem also with other fonts? Especially with fonts shipped with Windows or otherwise freely available for testing?

Comment: I was trying to connect the problem with fonts, but I was unable to trace the reason. I thought it was caused by the method, the fonts were embedded, but it lead me to nowhere.
In your opinion this situation may be caused by this font?

Comment: Well, at least it is not the data surrounding the font file in the PDF (e.g. the font descriptor dictionary) but the font file itself. There only is the question whether abcpdf breaks something in the font file while restricting it to the glyphs needed in the PDF, or whether already the original font file contains data making Adobe Reader for Android hickup.